Uploading files to MS Azure Storage
I need to upload a docx files to MS Azure Storage, for now, I am just using Postman to test it. I got a response 201 and see the files were successfully uploaded, but when I'm trying to download them (manually) they are all broken. Do I make some mistake in the request, can somebody check it, please?
cURL(some details replaced):
curl --location --request PUT 'https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test10.docx?SAS_token' \
--header 'x-ms-date: 2024-04-30T11:17:08.494Z' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' \
--header 'Content-Length: 17274' \
--header 'x-ms-version: 2020-04-08' \
--header 'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob' \
--form '=@"/Users/user/Desktop/folder/test.docx"'

The response was OK, also I see a file in container:

But when download the file is broken:

Also, if I upload it manually, it works. So, I'm sure, that the problem is somewhere in PUT request I'm using or somewhere in security settings.
Thank you.

The issue is with the following line in your request:
--form '=@"/Users/user/Desktop/folder/test.docx"'

Basically you are sending the file using multipart/form-data which is not really supported in Azure Storage. You will need to send the raw data.
Please try by replacing --form option with -T option and specify the file path.
Your command would be something like:
curl --location --request PUT 'https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test10.docx?SAS_token' \
--header 'x-ms-date: 2024-04-30T11:17:08.494Z' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' \
--header 'Content-Length: 17274' \
--header 'x-ms-version: 2020-04-08' \
--header 'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob' \
-T '/Users/user/Desktop/folder/test.docx'

